# Ajax request not giving output

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a .post() request

```
      function validateLogin()
        {
       var username = $("#username").val();
       var password= $("#password").val();
       var details = {"name": username, "password": password};
       console.log(details);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(details));


           $.post("getthedb.php", JSON.stringify(details), function(response)
           {


           if(response.code==0)
              {
             alert("Response: " + response.message);
             $("#myDiv").innerHTML = response.message;

              }
           else
              { 
             $("#myDiv").innerHTML = response.message;
              }


        }, "application/json");

     }
```

> getthedb.php

```
             <?php
              header('Content-type: application/json');
              $jsonobj = file_get_contents("php://input");
              $detail= json_decode($jsonobj);
              if(($detail->{'name'}=="abc") && ($detail->{'password'}=="abc")) 
                {
                $response1['code']=0;
                $response1['message']="Success";
                 }
              else
               {
                   $response1['code']=1;
                   $response1['message']="No Success";
               }

              $response  = json_encode($response1);
              echo $response;
                 ?>
```

This is not giving back any result,'console.log(details)' and 
'console.log(JSON.stringify(details))' produces the JSON object. how to debug this???

> where am i lagging here.??

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that it is easier to read. Thank you. Also your question is not clear. You are saying "This is not giving back any result" but also "console.log(details) and console.log(JSON.stringify(details)) produces the JSON object". So what's the problem now?

Comment: Why are you using file_get_contents("php://input");?

Answer (score 0):

If you code doesn't provide some **error** i assume that **your if** **down there** **isn't called** and *$response1* is **empty**. So no response to read.

```
if(($detail->{'name'}=="abc") && ($detail->{'password'}=="abc") 
{
    $response1['code']=0;
    $response1['message']="Success";
}
else ???

$response  = json_encode($response1); // Response1 is empty
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

missing `)` in `if loop`.

```
if(($detail->{'name'}=="abc") && ($detail->{'password'}=="abc")
```

should be

```
if(($detail->{'name'}=="abc") && ($detail->{'password'}=="abc"))
```

1. `$response1 array` not declared.
2. You haven't written `else` case

Comment: in console POST message is not been shown and $response1 = {}; declaration is ok..?

Comment: i haven't written else because I am checking with credentails abc and abc only

Comment: have u updated the if loop what i have changed above?

Comment: seems your json string not passing onto the php. If you have the json string such that $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}'; It will be converted to $obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; //